# Facebook style settings popup

Tags: css, facebook, popup

Maybe anybody knows a tutorial or thread of how to make a Facebook style popup with a triangle on the top?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

I think you will find this usefull.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/popup-with-css-triangle